# Docker with a new nameserver

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How I can add new nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` (dockerfile)?

On my dockerfile I use:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN echo "nameserver 10.111.122.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

On my test I use:

```
docker run --rm 746cb98d6c9b echo cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

I didn't get my change (the new nameserver)... So I try adding mannualy with

```
docker run --rm 746cb98d6c9b echo "nameserver 10.111.122.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

and I get

```
zsh: permission denied: /etc/resolv.conf
```

How I can change permission of this file OR use a root user OR use a chmod in docker files ? My real task is to add and dns server for my build of this dockerfile.

I'm using a linux mint.

I'm get a correct result with a ping test on docker run command (with `--dns`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, one of the ways you can add new DNS information to your container's build process is by adding some startup options to your Docker daemon. [The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) for that process reveals that the option you'll use is `--dns`. The location of your configuration file depends on your specific distro. On my Linux Mint machine, the file is in `/etc/default/docker`. On Linux Mint, look for the `DOCKER_OPTS=` line, and add the appropriate `--dns=x.x.x.x` entries to that line.

For example, if you want to use Google's DNS, you should change that line to look like this:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns=8.8.4.4 --dns=8.8.8.8"
```

Additionally, in the absense of `--dns` or `--dns-search` startup options, Docker will use the `/etc/resolv.conf` of the host it's running on instead.

Answer (score 3):

The DNS configuration of a Docker container may be adjusted during the creation of the container and does not need to be hard-coded in the Docker image itself.

Passing a single DNS server to the container works by providing the `--dns` parameter:

```
$ docker run --rm --dns=8.8.8.8 <image>
```

You're free to provide more than one DNS server and you can also define other DNS related options like the DNS search name or common DNS options:

```
$ docker run --rm --dns=8.8.8.8 --dns=8.8.4.4 --dns-search=your.search.domain --dns-opt=timeout:50 <image>
```

If you pass `cat /etc/resolv.conf` as command to your container, you can easily verify that the passed DNS configuration options made it into the container's DNS configuration:

```
$ docker run --rm --dns=8.8.4.4 --dns=8.8.8.8 --dns-search=your.domain.name --dns-opt=timeout:50 alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf

search your.domain.name
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options timeout:50
```

Please also refer to the `docker run` configuration which can be found at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/